# Where is my error in this combinations word problem?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> A student has to answer $10$ out of $13$ questions in an examination. The number of ways in which he can answer if he must answer at least $3$ of the first five questions is:

The answer is not $^5C_3 \times {^{10}C_7}$. Why?????

$C$ here is combination.

Comment: What if he answers 4/5 questions out of the first five questions. You need to add those ways too

Comment: Are there $13$ questions the exam or $15$?

Comment: @saulspatz, he already said in the question that 10 out 13 so there are 13 question in the exam.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Then I don't understand where the $10$ comes from,  Do you?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE!

Given the first five questions:
$ 1_q \:\: 2_q \:\: 3_q \:\: 4_q \:\: 5_q $

these are all the $10$ possibilities of choosing $3$ out of the $5$:

$\{1_q,2_q,3_q\}, \{1_q,2_q,4_q\}, \{1_q,2_q,5_q\} , \{1_q,3_q,4_q\} , 
\{1_q, 3_q, 5_q \}, \{ 1_q, 4_q, 5_q \} $

$\{2_q, 3_q, 4_q\} , \{2_q, 3_q, 5_q \} , \{2_q , 4_q, 5_q\}$

$\{3_q,4_q,5_q\}$

say the student answered the first $3$ out of the $5$ : $\{1_q,2_q,3_q\}$

‘then there are still’ $10$ questions left to choose from $\{4_q,5_q,...,13_q\}$ and the student answered the $7$ questions $4_q, 6_q, 7_q, 8_q, 9_q,10_q, 11_q$,

now say the student answered questions $1_q,3_q,4_q$ out of the $5$ first,
and then answered the $7$ more questions $2_q, 6_q, 7_q, 8_q, 9_q,10_q,11_q$,

in essence the student answered the same set of questions $\{1_q,2_q,3_q,4_q,6_q,7_q,8_q,9_q,10_q,11_q\}=\{1_q,3_q,4_q,2_q,6_q,7_q,8_q,9_q,10_q,11_q\}$
but just in a different order, but that is double counting nonetheless.

The key here is ***at least*** $3$ of the first $5$ questions, the student must answer $3$, any $3$, but they may answer more, and you could want to break it up into exactitudes, the student answers *exactly* $3$ of the first $5$, *exactly* $4$ of the first $5$, all $5$ of the first $5$ to avoid overlapping/double-counting.

Say the student answers *exactly* $3$ of the first five questions:

$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{8}{7}$$

The student may also answer *exactly* $4$ of the first five questions:

$$\binom{5}{4}\binom{8}{6}$$

and the student may also answer all $5$ of the first five questions:

$$\binom{5}{5}\binom{8}{5}$$

all possibilities is the sum of all these $\binom{5}{3}\binom{8}{7} +\binom{5}{4}\binom{8}{6}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{8}{5}=276$.

Comment: Go hang a salami; I'm a lasagna hog!

Comment: @Zubin it was a coin toss between those two! that one is wayyyy funnier tho XD

Answer (score 1):

Your solution implies the exam taker answers $3$ questions from the first $5$, and then $7$ questions from the remaining $10$.

This counts some of the combinations more than once.

For example, label the first $5$ question $A,B,C,D,E$, and the last $8$ as $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$.

Then you count say $ABCDEabcde$ several times, e.g.:

(ABC)DEabcde, (ABD)CEabcde, (CDE)ABabcde, etc...

In fact it counts each one $\binom{5}{3}=10$ times.

A different solution is to notice that if you answer $10$ questions from $13$, then, by the Pigeonhole Principle, you must have answered at least $2$ from the first $5$, and there are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to do that. So the answer is $\binom{13}{10}-\binom{5}{2}=286-10=276$.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the Textbook question in India if you recollect. First, you divide the number of questions into two categories- the first $5$ questions and the remaining $8$ questions.

Now pay attention to the words of the question. it says

> " he must answer atleast 3 questions..."

and of course

> student has to answer 10 questions

So the student may any $n$ number of questions among the first 5 and any $m$ number of questions among the last 8. The only conditions given are

> n is greater than 3 and at most 5

> $m+n=10$

You can work out the other number of possibilities by yourself and add them up

(this was supposed to be a comment)